# Is there a way in rails where i can format a line of text?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to change one word in a line of text to another. I know that html_escape changes it from & to &amp. How do i do the opposite?
For example:

```
<%= title %>
```

where i want to change every instance of "&amp" in title to &. Any help to achieve this would be helpful.

P.S - title is a property in a collection and i would be using a do to loop through the collection.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could write a view helper which is rails speak for create a method that accepts a variable that you can work with, place it in application_helper.rb which lives in app/helpers folder, that way it is accessible to all your views.

You could call it something like `def render_title(title)` and you'd call it from your view like so `<%= render_title(title) %>`

```
def render_title(title)
  title.gsub /&amp;/, "&"
  #Or
  CGI::unescapeHTML(title)
end
```

But be careful when unescaping HTML when you do not trust the source of the values, it's dangerous